# restart the class with initial argument value python

Tags: python, class

I am trying to do a class to manipulate a nested list ,

a_list = [ a, b, c, d, e, f, g] will be an initial argument , then I will have some other methods to manipulate the list. However, I will need to keep a copy of the original list, that by anytime I can restart it to the initial stage by calling the restart() method ,

i tried a couple of times but it didn't work, can anyone give me a hand?

```
class Sample:
    def __init__(self, a_list, count):
        self.__a_list = a_list
        self.__count = 0 
        self.__reset_list = a_list.copy()  

    def restart(self):
        self.__a_list = self.__reset_list
        return
```

This is a full test case, it did not get back to the original value:

```
class Sample:
    def __init__(self, a_list, count=0):
        self.__a_list = a_list
        self.__count = 0 
        self.__reset_list = a_list.copy()  
    
    def set_update(self):
        self.__a_list[2][2] = "S"

    def restart(self):
        self.__a_list = self.__reset_list
        return

    def __str__(self):
        result_list = self.__a_list
        result = ''
        for i in range(len(result_list)):
            for j in range(len(result_list[i])):
                result += result_list[i][j] + ' '
            if i < len(result_list) -1: 
                result += '\n'
        return result

    


test = [
    ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*'],
    ['*', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
    ['*', ' ', ' ', '#', 'P', ' ', ' ', '*'],
    ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*', ' ', '#', '*'],
    ['*', 'o', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '*'],
    ['*', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'o', '*'],
    ['*', '*', '*', ' ', '*', '*', '*', '*']
]


a_case =   Sample(test)

print(a_case)

a_case.set_update()

print(a_case)

a_case.restart()

print(a_case)
```

Comment: your method does modification to which list ? self.__a_list or self.__reset_list?

Comment: try to do modification to  self.__a_list ,  the self.__reset_list was my original intention to keep a copy of the initial value before gets any updates done

Comment: can you add an example of the modification you are performing? i have done. and your code works fine. it is retaining the original list in self.__reset_list

Comment: I have updated the main block and please see the full test case

Comment: @jawan218 added the answer, please check

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy the list on restart:

```
def restart(self):
    self.__a_list = self.__reset_list.copy()
```

Otherwise `__a_list` points to *the same* list as `__reset_list`, and the latter will reflect any modifications made to `__a_list`

Comment: Thanks Mathias, however, when I tried to initiate a instance , say a = Sample(),  then I called the method a.restart(),   it still didnt get back to the original state if i had some updates done

Answer (score 1):

One thing i noticed was, this issue is not happening in 1D array. as a solution you can use deepcopy. check the answer below.

```
import copy
class Sample:
    def __init__(self, a_list, count=0):
        self.__a_list = a_list
        self.__count = 0 
        self.__reset_list = copy.deepcopy(a_list) #use deepcopy to copy the array
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, just wondering if there is any other solution than using imports? imports is prohibited in my environment , really appreciated your help

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a solution by using the nested list to nested tuple conversion

## using tuples

```
class Sample:
    def __init__(self, a_list, count=0):
        self.__a_list = a_list
        self.__count = 0 
        self.__reset_list = a_list.copy()     
        self.__tracks = []
    
    def set_update(self,i,j):
        current_copy = tuple(tuple(i) for i in self.__a_list)
        self.__tracks.append(current_copy)
        self.__a_list[i][j] = "S"

    def restart(self):
        initial_copy = [list(i) for i in self.__tracks[0]] 
        self.__a_list = initial_copy
        while len(self.__tracks) > 0:
            self.__tracks.pop()  
        return self.__a_list  

    def undo(self): 
        self.__tracks.pop()
        last_copy = [list(i) for i in self.__tracks[-1]] 
        print(last_copy)
        self.__a_list = last_copy
        self.__tracks.pop()  
        return self.__a_list  

    def __str__(self):
        result_list = self.__a_list
        result = ''
        for i in range(len(result_list)):
            for j in range(len(result_list[i])):
                result += result_list[i][j] + ' '
            if i < len(result_list) -1: 
                result += '\n'
        return result


test = [
    ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*'],
    ['*', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
    ['*', ' ', ' ', '#', 'P', ' ', ' ', '*'],
    ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*', ' ', '#', '*'],
    ['*', 'o', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '*'],
    ['*', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'o', '*'],
    ['*', '*', '*', ' ', '*', '*', '*', '*']
]


a_case =   Sample(test)

print(a_case)

a_case.set_update(2,2)

print(a_case)

a_case.set_update(2,3)

print(a_case)

a_case.set_update(3,3)

print(a_case)


a_case.undo()

print(a_case)

a_case.restart()

print(a_case)
```